# What is the p values taken by sklearn chi2

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am trying to understand the implementation of the sklearn chi2 for feauture selection algorithm.
I think I understand the chi2 formula.
[image]

[image]

After getting this value we will see the table for 1 degree of freedom and according to ou need choose the p value.If chi2 value is greater than keep it otherwise ignore it.

My question is how does sklearn package choose this p-value on its own?It just requires X and y array as input.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.chi2.html

and are the chi2 scores always normalized? 
link to the paper-http://courses.ischool.berkeley.edu/i256/f06/papers/yang97comparative.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to perform [**univariate feature selection**](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#univariate-feature-selection):

1. For each feature, you compute some kind of a statistic (in your case a chisquared-statistic)
2. Create a set of (hopefully) most important features by combining 1) with some selection method ([SelectKBest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest), [SelectPercentile](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectPercentile.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectPercentile))

So going back to your question, I think you misunderstood the following point:

- You always run the chi2 test for **all** features and then you only keep those that had highest chi2-statistic (=lowest p value). You do not specify a cutoff threshold since your is goal to keep the **most informative features**. If you insist and really want to use a cutoff threshold then you would have to write your own Transformer and  it is not obvious at all what this cutoff value should be (even when applied to p-values).

Comment: Are chi square values always normalized?I am refering a paper whih is heavely cited too where this is mentioned..I have added the link in the question.

Comment: I recommend you see the implementation here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/feature_selection/univariate_selection.py#L171

Comment: I have seen this implementation...I dont think they should be normalized but the paper says so...